# Java SQL query memory leak

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I have an application that iterates over an amount of resultSets and queries additional information for every row from a different table.

The rough structure is like this:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    ResultSet result = database.connection.createStatement()
                           .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM entities");
    ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    while (result.next() {
        Entity entity = EntityFactory.createById(result.getInt("id"));
        entities.add(entity);
    }
}

// EntityFactory
public static Entity createById(int id) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM sampling_data WHERE id = ")
                            .append(id);
    ResultSet result = database.connection.createStatement()
                            .executeQuery(sql.toString());
    result.first();
    EntityData data = new EntityData(25);

    for (int sample = 1; sample <= 25; sample++) {
        String sample_R = new StringBuilder("sample_")
                              .append(sample).append("_R").toString();
        String sample_G = new StringBuilder("sample_")
                              .append(sample).append("_G").toString();
        String sample_B = new StringBuilder("sample_")
                              .append(sample).append("_B").toString();

        int r = resultSet.getInt(sample_R);
        int g = resultSet.getInt(sample_G);
        int b = resultSet.getInt(sample_B);

        data.add(r, g, b);
    }

    return new Entity(data);
}
```

Which results in a OutOfMemoryException.

How can I make the loop (or the whole methods) more memory efficient?

Comment: Oh, you need [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) or the such... How many results do you have there in the `ResultSet`?

Comment: I have VisualVM, and it's HeapDump shows that `String` and `char[]` use up around 95% of the heap. The result set is around 2500 rows large, but will get considerably larger in the future.

Comment: In your main method, are you querying over one of these 75 `sample_*` columns or some other columns? Storing something like RBG samples in a database and mapping every sample to its own object might not be the best way. What's the overall goal you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: In `createById`, are you executing a new query? You replaced that code with comments in the posted example? So do you **close** that child resultset in `createById`?

Comment: No, I call `ResultSet result = databaseConnection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sampling_data");`

Comment: As duffymo suggested, your schema is most likely not a good fit for your data. How does your schema look, something like `sampling_data (id, sample_[1-25]_R, sample_[1-25]_G, sample_[1-25]_B)`? If there's no other columns, you should change this to `(id, index, sample_R, sample_G, sample_B)`, or even drop the `index` column completely: `(id, sample_R, sample_G, sample_B)` (if you don't explicitly need that column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest problem was (I think) that createById did not close result set and statement.
Further it makes sense to not have nx1 queries.

```
    try {
        Statement stmt = database.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sampling_data d"
            + " WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM entities e WHERE e.id = d.id)");
        List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        while (result.next()) {
            Entity entity = EntityFactory.createById(result);
            entities.add(entity);
        }
        result.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

And

```
// EntityFactory
public static Entity createById(ResultSet resultSet) {
    EntityData data = new EntityData(25);
    for (int sample = 1; sample <= 25; sample++) {
        String sample_R = new StringBuilder("sample_").append(sample).append("_R").toString();
        String sample_G = new StringBuilder("sample_").append(sample).append("_G").toString();
        String sample_B = new StringBuilder("sample_").append(sample).append("_B").toString();
        int r = resultSet.getInt(sample_R);
        int g = resultSet.getInt(sample_G);
        int b = resultSet.getInt(sample_B);

        data.add(r, g, b);
    }

    return new Entity(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell from the glimpses of code, but I gather it has to do with too many rows fetched altogether.

You should use [setFetchSize(int rows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) on your `Statement` with a reasonable number of rows (100 maybe).

```
    private static int FETCH_SIZE = 100;
    ...
    Statement stmt = databaseConnection.createStatement()
    stmt.setFetchSize();
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sampling_data");
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the getInt() method uses a lot of memory when executing
>   in a loop.

This is incorrect.  There's nothing special about `getInt()` that causes your problem.

Your schema breaks first normal form for relational databases.  Seeing `sample_1_R, sample_1_G, sample_1_B` makes me question your other decisions as well.  This is obviously a `1:m` relationship.  Same goes for magic numbers like 25.

I'd wonder why you're doing all that stuff with String builder and ints.  I'd encapsulate those RGB values into a meaningful object, like `java.awt.Color`.

How much data are we talking about here?

```
25*3*32*2500 ~ 5.7 MB
```

That's not much for your 2500 rows, each with 75 integer values.  Something else is going on that's not clear from your code.

Update:

You're making the classic `(n+1)` query mistake in this code.  You get all the entities, then loop over them to get the RGB values.  I'd recommend doing a JOIN and bringing them back all at once.  That may not explain your memory issue, but it is a problem.

You repeatedly build up the column name when you query for RGB values.  That's totally wasteful.  Make them `static final String` instances in an array.

Comment: I edited my code and added everything I previously skipped in the comments. Maybe now it's easier to find the error?